# Как удалить кеш сайта у пользователя?

Tags: кэширование, php, http, html

Ситуация следующая: был сайт www.mysite.com оставил много разных куков, кэшированных картинок и стилей css. Сайт обновился, но кэшированная информация у пользователей мешает нормальной работе (особенно google chrome 29). Если отчистить историю+кэш+куки всё отлично начинает работать. Можно ли как то принудительно при первом заходе заставить браузер удалить информацию по этому сайту, а далее уже кэшировать "как всегда"?

Comment: Я читал про это, в таком случае он не будет кэшироваться вообще, а мне в идеале хотелось бы "отчистить" а потом кэшировать как всегда

Comment: Пройдитесь по домам ваших посетителей и почистите тогда им кэш :)
Как вы представляете себе - все пользователи зайдут к вам одновременно в тот период, когда у вас сервер будет отдавать эти хедеры? Раскиньте мозгами - "маркируйте" очищенных с помощью куков - зашел пользователь? Зашел. Есть кука? Нет. Тогда получи с хедером и поставь новую "маркер"-куку. Следующий раз зайдет - проверяйте "маркер"-куку. Есть? Отлично - не шлите больше хедеров.
Продержите такое на время, пока не почувствуете, что пора завязывать с этим механизмом и все "проапдейтились".

Comment: Это и правда реально работает!

Comment: я бы маркер в сессию ставить, зачем оно в куке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

Или слать `header` в страницах (как-то в таком стиле)

```
header('Expires: Sat, 03 Aug 2013 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас, это то не беда, чтоб на сайте отображались css правильно (как я понял вы его меняете периодически и это ломает отображение сайта) надо всего лишь сделать все время новый адрес загрузки css вот так:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/css.css?<?php echo time();?>" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

и все браузер будет думать что файл css все время новый и верстка ломаться не будет

а вот у меня другая проблема, на сайте есть авторизация и иногда случается что на некоторые страницы (закрытые не авторизованным пользователям) зайти не получается, дело в том, что браузер в этих случаях даже и не пытается проверить авторизацию и сразу выкидывает на главную, как не аторизованного пользователя. Причем если очистить кеш браузера сразу все работает правильно!

я уже кучу сайтов с авторизацией сделал и такого ниразу не встречал, что мне делать? я просто в шоке.

P.S. кеш браузере запретил всеми способами: через php заголовки, через .htaccess и обычными метатегами nocach

Comment: Вот написал это сообщение и меня осенило! я понял проблему свою, оказалось, что по просьбе SEO-шника, я все свои редиректы (которые посылают не авторизованных пользователей) поменял на 301-ые. а это же постоянный!!!!

Comment: Если у вас есть вопрос, задаёте его, воспользовавшись соответствующей кнопкой. А пихать вопрос внутрь ответа не надо

Comment: Не хватило репутации, чтобы явно заминусовать ответ. Ты вставляешь (коряво) таймстамп в название файла, разумеется это решит проблему с кэшированием. каждую секунду буквально будет решать, при каждом переходе между страницами. 
(Если кажется, что я занимаюсь некропостингом - сегодня, в 2022 году, кто-то воспользовался этим ответом, пришлось объяснять, что кэширование не просто так придумали)

Answer (score 0):

Обычно автообновление стилей делают припиской с версией:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/css.css?v1.0" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю лучше будет сделать так:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/style.css?<?=filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/css/style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet"/>
```